# Lifting a handkerchief before signing the Ketubah?

Tags: halacha, wedding, transactions

I know at a Jewish wedding, just before the Ketubah is signed, the groom picks up a handkerchief in front of everyone.  I remember this has something to do with "kinyan chalifin"; could someone please refresh my memory: whose handkerchief is this, and what exactly is being acquired by whom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the name of Rabbi Lamm, taken from: http://www.myjewishlearning.com/life/Life_Events/Weddings/Liturgy_Ritual_and_Custom/Ketubah/Details_II.shtml

> The Act of Acquisition (Kinyan). In
>   order to seal all of the stipulated
>   obligations, and to assure that the
>   document is not asmakhta (based on
>   speculation), the rabbis required the
>   legal formality of kinyan, the act of
>   acquisition. Because the bride cannot
>   take possession of all the property,
>   the groom affirms it by a symbolic act
>   called kinyan suddar.
>
> Thus, at the wedding, the rabbi or one
>   of the witnesses gives a handkerchief
>   or other article (but not a coin) on
>   behalf of the recipient (the bride) to
>   the groom. The groom then returns it.
>   Then they record in the ketubah,
>   ve'kanina ("and we have completed the
>   act of acquisition"). This symbolic
>   act must be seen clearly by the
>   witnesses, who are the makers of the
>   contract, before they sign to its
>   validity. If the ketubah is
>   calligraphed by a scribe, or printed
>   in advance of the wedding, one letter
>   of the word ve'kanina (or the whole
>   word) is usually omitted so that the
>   ketubah is technically not completed
>   before the kinyan itself is made. If
>   this custom is overlooked, it does not
>   alter the ketubah's validity, so long
>   as the witnesses in fact witness the
>   kinyan-transfer of the handkerchief.

Comment: Thanks.  The nuts-and-bolts of the symbolic transaction are that the  bride is acquiring the various rights described in the ketubah FROM the groom, so someone on her behalf (usually the rabbi) hands him a handkerchief.  (From http://www.mail-archive.com/daf-discuss@shemayisrael.com/msg00005.html)