# What is the order in terms of level of cavod for sheva brachos under the chuppah?

Tags: wedding, sheva-brachos, honors

In order of cavod of the sheva brachos 1-7 what are the levels of cavod or importance for each of the brachos? There are gonna be a lot of rabbis at my wedding in a few days

Comment: Yafeh LaLev (EH 62:6) says it's "good and pleasant" to have the Sheva Brachot said by a Kohein if possible.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/seven-brochos-at-a-wedding

Comment: This would be an appropriate question for the mesader kedushin. Mine said all of the brachos at the chupa and the sheva brachos at the meal were split. During our honeymoon a rav said all of the brachos at the sheva brachos during the meals.