# Must the first and second bracha of sheva brachos be said together by one person?

Tags: halacha, blessing, wedding, sheva-brachos

Must the first and second bracha of sheva brachos be said together by one person? Or may they be split between two honorees?

There are a lot of people who I will need to honor at my wedding in a few days and trying to figure out how, so sources on the matter that I can bring to ask my mesader kiddushin would be wonderful.

Comment: Honor them by inviting them.

Comment: http://www.ravaviner.com/2016/02/honoring-rabbis-at-weddings.html

Answer (score 6):

[The longstanding traditional Jewish practice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65950/759) is to have all 7 blessings said by one person. Those (see that link) who discuss the new practice of splitting up the blessings do not differentiate in their argumentation between any of the shorter blessings. See too [Benei Vanim 4:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20023&st=&pgnum=24) who discusses your question and sees no Halachic reason to distinguish the particular pair you reference.

Comment: interesting idea. have you ever seen that actually done at a wedding all of them said by one person?

Comment: @Dude Yes. Mine, for instance.

Comment: @Dude This guy's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQNjSKdGeQ0

Answer (score 2):

At my wedding, we split the seven Brachos into 6 honors (the first and second brachos together, since the 1st is not unique to a wedding, then each subsequent bracha alone).

I have been to many, many weddings and this same paradigm was used.

The Mesader Kedushin was Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky.