# Chosson leading the bentching

Tags: marriage, shulchan-aruch, sheva-brachos, even-haezer

Can a Chosson lead the bentching excluding the Sheva Brachos? I ask this because I understand that other people lead but let’s say the Chosson was in a restaurant and wanted to make a minyan for Sheva Brachos and he leads but doesn’t say the Sheva Brachos.

Can this be done?

This is not Halacha L’maaseh!

Comment: `but let’s say the Chosson was in a restaurant and wanted to make a minyan for Sheva Brachos` not sure why that's relevant for your question. You're simply asking if he can lead the bentching...

Comment: Just in case someone asked why he wants to lead. Just trying to cover all basis.

Comment: Even with your story I don't understand why he wants to lead...

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/72951/759

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=28b https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%98#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%98_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%91 The simple read is not just that he can lead but that he should lead since he's the most honored person there. I've never seen anyone do this though and I don't know why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nitei Gavriel - Nisuin2 99:3](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&st=&pgnum=219) says a Chasan may lead the Zimun.