What is the bare minimum that needs to happen for a jewish wedding to take place?
I would like to know the raw components of what makes a Jewish marriage valid. What is the sine qua non, and what is considered "extra" or "minhag"? For example, is it enough for the man to give the woman something of a certain value or does he have to say the phrase, "harei at mekudeshet li..."

What are you trying to accomplish?

I don't understand why this question is unclear. Someone wants a wedding that is considered to be a marriage under Jewish law. They don't want some aspects of a typical Jewish wedding such as the giving of the ring and saying "harei at mekudeshet li". So I want to know, what has to take place in order that an Orthodox Jewish marriage has been enacted.

To oversimplify, a Jewish wedding as conducted today consists of two separate procedures: “kiddushin” (betrothal) after which the woman is forbidden to other men without a divorce but cannot yet live with her new husband, and “nisuin” (marriage) after which they live together as man and wife. Are you asking for the minimum requirements to have carried out  both processes, or only one of them? Do you want to know what satisfies the requirements according to all/most opinions, or only according to some opinions (such that we still may need to treat them as married, but only as a stringency)?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/what-do-i-need-to-make-a-jewish-wedding

There are enough minute details that they really need to run it by a rabbi first, even if that rabbi doesn't show up. But you can see Mishna Kiddushin 1:1.

@Joel K - I am asking for the minimum requirements to have carried out both processes according to most/all opinions.

@Sheldon marriage is an english word. It doesn't have a precise hebrew/jewish equivalent. When you say "considered to be a marriage under Jewish law" we don't know what that means since there isn't a concept of "marriage" under Jewish law. If you better specify what status you're looking for, we can better understand what steps would be needed to achieve that status. For instance, there are statuses where they would need a divorce to marry anyone else, but don't inherit each other. Where they do inherit but can't live together. Etc.

Is the question asking if a particular aspect is me'akeiv or whether the precise wording has to be used?

@rosends - if the precise wording has to be used

@Sheldon If you have a question on a specific detail, then try asking about that directly. Now, to the extent it's even comprehensible, the question is quite broad and would require discussion of many, many different points (which may deter answerers who don't have the time or ability to produce something so comprehensive).
