# Why is the ketuba left incomplete until the signing?

Tags: wedding, aleph-bet-letters, writing-printing, legal-documents, ketubah

In the ketuba, the ק in the word "וקנינא" is sometimes left incomplete until the time that the ketuba is signed. Why is the ketuba left incomplete?

Comment: "Sometimes ketubahs are left with a word, a letter, or part of a letter missing so that the ketubah may be completed just before it is signed. The word usually left incomplete is the word v'kinyanah, which translates as “the kinyan” or “the agreement” and appears close to the end of the ketubah text... If only a letter or part of a letter is to be left out, this is usually the letter kof in the word v'kinyanah." http://www.netplaces.com/jewish-weddings/pre-ceremony-traditions/signing-the-ketubah.htm

Comment: @Dan, yes, but why?

Comment: why the kuf or why the entire practice?

Comment: @Dan, Why leave anything incomplete?

Comment: " If the ketubah is calligraphed by a scribe, or printed in advance of the wedding, one letter of the word ve'kanina (or the whole word) is usually omitted so that the ketubah is technically not completed before the kinyan itself is made. If this custom is overlooked it does not alter the ketubah's validity, so long as the witnesses in fact witness the kinyan-transfer of the handkerchief." http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/465168/jewish/The-Marriage-Contract-Ketubah.htm

Comment: @Dan, Yes, I understand all of this, but why would we want the ketuba to not be complete before the kinyan is made?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/215/1362 check oout the second paragraph of the answer -- the ketubah is supposed to be written recording the act of kinyan so its completion right at the act is as if it is a fresh testament of the act, signed by witnesses.

Comment: Maybe one of the above links should be added to the question as motivation

Answer (score 4):

The [Aruch Hashulchan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9103&st=&pgnum=127) writes that one is allowed to write spare contracts. He says that we don't say that it looks like a lie (the scribe writes that someone borrowed money before it happened) unless there are witnesses signed there.

However, he says that some say not to write the last part of the contract (the Toref). This is usually taken care of by not writing "VeKinyana".